How can I center the items in .jsx file?
I'm very at the beginning of web development. I'm currently learning Node.js and React with Vite. I couldn't center the header menu properly and things I found on internet didn't work. It is probably something very elementary but as I said I'm a beginner.
Thanks for your help!
function Header() {
    const ulStyle = {
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "row",
        backgroundColor: "#2b2b2b",
        alignItems: "center"
    }
    const liStyle = {
        flexGrow: "1",
        flexBasis: "0",
        position: "relative"
    }
    return (
        <header>
            <h1>Website</h1>
            <nav>
                <ul style={ulStyle}>
                    <li><a href="#" style={liStyle}>Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" style={liStyle}>About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" style={liStyle}>Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" style={liStyle}>Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
    );
}

Or in plain HTML


.ulStyle {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: #2b2b2b;
  align-items: center;
}

.liStyle {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  position: relative;
}
<header>
  <h1>Website</h1>
  <nav>
    <ul class="ulStyle">
      <li><a href="#" class="liStyle">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="liStyle">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="liStyle">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="liStyle">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>




The property for alignment on the main flex axis is justify-content; align-items works on the secondary axis.

In plain CSS your rules will be different as they don't use camel-case: flex-direction, background-color etc.

@Andy oops, that was my fault. I added the snippet

As @CBbore pointed out you just need to change the alignItems to justify-content.
This is how it will look in your code


.ulStyle {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: #2b2b2b;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center; /* here */

}

.liStyle {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  position: relative;
}
<header>
  <h1>Website</h1>
  <nav>
    <ul class="ulStyle">
      <li><a href="#" class="liStyle">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="liStyle">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="liStyle">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="liStyle">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>




The plain CSS is wrong - see my comment below the post.

Thank you for not downgrading me but for explaining it to me, but I can't understand what you mean, do you have a link on the subject? I want to understand more

Your solution worked, thank you very much.

In the question to explain the code the OP has examples of using both CSS within a JavaScript object (in which case the rules are in camelCase), and in plain CSS but they have the plain CSS example wrong: the rules should not be in camelCase but hyphenated. If you change backgroundColor to background-color you should see the difference in your snippet. justify-content only works because that's the correct rule syntax.

I've corrected the plain css part of the question, thank you @Andy

Thanks again for the explanation!!
And about the repair...
